# Writing logistic regression output to a text file

Tags: stata, logistic-regression

I am running a logistic regression using Stata 12 on Windows 7.

I want to write the `Odds Ratios` , `P>|z|` and the `[95% Conf. Interval]` output values to a text file.

Below you can find the code I have tried:

```
use "http://dss.princeton.edu/training/Panel101.dta" , clear

file open TABLES using "values.txt", write replace //create temporary text 
file write TABLES "the_var ,Odds , P_value, 95%CI" _n // columns headers

logistic y_bin x1 // run the model

matrix list e(b) //list the coficients output
mat values = e(b) //attach the coeficient matrix to a matrix values

local the_var= "x1" // get the variable name
local logODD=values[1,1] //get the log odds

//the problem is extracting these values
local P_value=P>|z|
local  95%CI= [95% Conf. Interval]

file write TABLES "`the_var' , `Odds' , `P_value' ,  `95%CI'"  _n
```

I have also tried the *community-contributed* commands `estout` and `esttab` but without success since the returned `e(b)` matrix does not contain the results I want.

Answer (score 0):

The results you need are returned by the `logistic` command in `r()`:

```
use "https://dss.princeton.edu/training/Panel101.dta", clear

logistic y_bin x1

matrix A = r(table)
matrix list r(table)

r(table)[9,2]
            y_bin:     y_bin:
               x1      _cons
     b   1.637293  2.9519564
    se  1.0554607   1.422384
     z  .76483941  2.2465092
pvalue  .44436718  .02467141
    ll  .46281759  1.1480562
    ul   5.792192  7.5902614
    df          .          .
  crit   1.959964   1.959964
 eform          1          1
```

With some manipulation and the help of `esttab` it is very easy to export everything:

```
matrix A = ( A[1, 1...] \ A[4..6, 1...] )'

esttab matrix(A) using A.txt, mlabels(none)

type A.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------
                        b       pvalue           ll           ul
----------------------------------------------------------------
y_bin                                                           
x1               1.637293     .4443672     .4628176     5.792192
_cons            2.951956     .0246714     1.148056     7.590261
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

An alternative is also the *community-contributed* command `mat2txt`:

```
mat2txt, matrix(A) saving(A) 

type A.txt
        b       pvalue  ll      ul      
y_bin:x1          1.637293       .44436718       .46281759        5.792192      
y_bin:_cons      2.9519564       .02467141       1.1480562       7.5902614
```

You can download and use both as follows:

```
ssc install estout
```

```
ssc install mat2txt
```